# zendframe work phpUnit warning

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

after downloading Zend framework 1.11  on Ubuntu 11 ,when I try to create new project I got warning php_Unit was not found in your include path,after I had installed the phpUnit I got a lot of other warning so what the problem here ?? and how to set it ?

Comment: You expect someone to troubleshoot an error without knowing what the error is?

Comment: mm i expect someone face this error on ubuntu 11 ! because on ubuntu 10 there is no problem with it !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check PHP's path variable.  You can put this in your script to reveal it:

```
echo get_include_path();
```

It will show probably a handful of different system paths where PHP's autoloader will look for the classes it needs.  Make sure PHPUnit is in one of these paths, or modify your path to include the location of PHPUnit on your system.  It sounds like maybe Ubuntu 11 introduced a regression where either the default PHP path or the location of PHPUnit no longer match up.